# angular material 2 - how to change mat-form-fields and mat-form custom CSS

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want mat-form-fields / mat-input custom CSS

> Example1) angular material 2

```
<mat-form-field >
            <input matInput
                   [(ngModel)]="affiliateForm.name"
                   required name="affiliate_name"
                   placeholder="test">
</mat-form-field>
```

> Result : view.html
>
> default : [image] invaild : 
>   [image]

> custom global CSS  : global.css

```
.mat-input-infix.mat-form-field-infix{
                border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

> Result : view.html
>   default : [image]
>   i want invaild : [image]
>
> ```
>           how to change custom invaild CSS Style?
>           thank you have a good day.
> ```

Comment: For change the styles of material inputs with css => stackoverflow.com/a/54409733/2736742

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ng-invalid` and `ng-invalid` classes like so:

```
input.ng-valid {
    border: 2px solid green;
}
input.ng-invalid {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Angular adds these extra classes for you **dynamically** only if you are using FormGroup.

```
//*.component.ts
constructor() {
    this.affiliateForm = new FormGroup({
        affiliateName: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    })
}
```

And template like so:

```
<!-- *.component.html -->
<form [formGroup]="affiliateForm">
    <mat-form-field >
        <input matInput
               formControlName="affiliateName"
               placeholder="test">
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```